# How to connect to multiple SocketMobile Scanner (CHS 7Mi) at the same time in SPP Mode (C# Windows Forms, Socket ScanAPI SDK 10)

Tags: socketscan, socketmobile

Is there a way to connect to multiple scanners at the same time in SPP Mode?

I am using the Socket ScanAPI SDK 10 (the ScanApiHelper class) in a C# Windows Forms Project as host.

I changed the serialport setting from ScanAPI to e.g. SerialPorts=COM3:;COM6: (inbound ports)

But only one scanner connects to the host. If i turn off one scanner the other one connects immediately. But connecting two scanners at the same time does not work. It seems both scanners are communicating over the same com port.

Also it does not work with the official Socket Scan 10 Software from www.socketmobile.com (i tested on Windows 7 and 8.1)

Answer (score 1):

For posterity's sake, here is the complete answer.

#### The cause

By default, the CHS uses SDP to look for all incoming serial ports, but only attempts to connect to the first one. If the port is busy - i.e. another scanner is already connected - it gives up.

#### The solution

> ***Caveat emptor**: This solution has not been tested on the full range of Bluetooth stacks. It should work, but **there may be side-effects**. If you experience any, please report them to us.*

Your CHS can be configured to try to connect to up to 8 different serial ports on the host device. Instead of quitting after failing to connect to the first serial port, in `Scan Mode 1` the CHS will try the next serial port until it either finds a port it can connect to or it has tried all the ports it found using SDP.

### 1D scanners and 8Qi

> *Note*: If you have a laser scanner, you will need to print out these barcodes to scan them.

1. *Factory reset* your scanner

   *Hover to reveal barcode*

   > [image: Socket Mobile CHS scanner factory reset barcode]
2. Enable *SPP mode*

   *Hover to reveal barcode*

   > [image: Socket Mobile CHS scanner SPP mode barcode]
3. Enable *Scan Mode 1*

   *Hover to reveal barcode*

   > [image: Socket Mobile CHS 1D scanner "Scan Mode 1" barcode]

### 2D scanners (excl. 8Qi)

1. *Factory reset* your scanner

   *Hover to reveal barcode*

   > [image: Socket Mobile CHS scanner factory reset barcode]
2. Enable *SPP mode*

   *Hover to reveal barcode*

   > [image: Socket Mobile CHS scanner SPP mode barcode]
3. Enable *Scan Mode 1*

   *Hover to reveal barcode*

   > [image: Socket Mobile CHS scanner "Scan Mode 1" barcode]

#### Revert

Don't need `Scan Mode 1` anymore? Scanning the *factory reset* barcode for your scanner will clear all settings and put your scanner back in the default mode.

Answer (score 0):

The support from socketmobile told me to scan the barcode for "Scan Mode 1".

Now connecting to multiple scanners at the same time works perfectly